# How to implement hashCode() correctly to use it in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashcode

I am writing a Java application in which a user can receive some messages in form of images. There are text messages hidden in these images, using steganographic algorithm. If an image has been edited, before the user has read the message, a warning should pop out. Now, my idea is that, before one user sends the image to another, a the image gets hashed and stored as a value into the receiver's HashMap. Key to the hash value is the path to that image.

When the user receives the image, before the decryption, they first need to hash the selected image, then compare the hash of that image, with the hash previously added to their HashMap. Here is my code:

```
public String hashTheImage(byte[] image) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    return byteArray2Hex(md.digest(image));
}

private static String byteArray2Hex(final byte[] hash) {
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    for (byte b : hash) {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }
    return formatter.toString();
}
```

These methods hash the image. Then I do the following:

```
receiver.getMap().put(image.getPath(), this.hashTheImage(imageBytes));
```

Now, this is my method where I am trying to check if the two hashes are equal:

```
private boolean checkForChanges(String path, String newlyGeneratedHash){
    String receiverHash = receiver.getMap().get(path);
    if(!newlyGeneratedHash.equals(receiverHash)){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Image has been edited!", 
            "ERROR!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here I get that the receiverHash is null. I know that I am supposed to override hashCode() and equals() method, but I am not sure how, since I only need it for Strings. 
If anyone can give me an idea, I would really appreciate it. Please don't be rude, comment only if you can and want to help. Thanks

Comment: If you can guarantee that the paths on sending and receiving side are identical, you could just use [`String`'s `hashCode()`-implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--). Keep in mind that only the keys in a `HashMap` get hashed, not the values.

Comment: I don't quite understand where you would want to override `equals` and `hashCode` in your code. Your `Map`'s key set is parametrized with `String`s that represent the image's path, and `String`s already override those methods so you won't have duplicate entries in your key set. Your `Map`'s values are *also* `String`s, which you are comparing with `equals` in your `checkForChanges` method. Assuming your hashing strategy is solid enough, you shouldn't need anything else.

Comment: @Turing85 Good idea, since I am certain that the paths are identical. Can you just please explain a bit more how exactly I could use it when searching for the needed value? Is it enough to write it as    `receiver.getMap().containsKey(path.hashCode);`  I would use this code to determine if the path is stored in the Map. Sorry if it's a silly question, I am just a bit confused. Thanks

Comment: @Mena yes, that is what I first thought as well, but I don't understand why I get `false` when calling `reciever.getMap().containsKey(path);`. I am absolutely sure that it does contain that path.

Comment: The problem lies somewhere else. You are not putting the SHA-256 code into the map, or you are loosing that entry.

Comment: @ivaa14 you call `receiver.getMap().containsKey(path)`. The `HashMap` handles everything else.

Comment: @ivaa14 that means the path is not in the `Map`'s key set when you're checking. You probably want to debug your code: if you're sure the `put` method is invoked in time, maybe the path is not what you expect. Or, you may be having more subtle, multithread-related issues.

Comment: I have solved it. The problem was with the receiver's map itself. It did not get saved correctly, so in the moment of searching, it actually didn't have any values in it.

Comment: You don’t need to convert your hashes to Strings.  You can just store the byte arrays, and compare them with [Arrays.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-byte:A-byte:A-).